# Framework или и без него обойдемся?

Tags: responsive, framework, bootstrap, css

Меня мучает со вчерашнего дня один вопрос. Вот возмем фрейм Bootstrap. Я хочу создать отзывчивый дизайн. Так для его создания если я буду использовать % и media queries, то это будет равносильно бутстрапу? Я именно про responsive design. Про фишки и достоинства бута не будем решать и оглашать. Так в чем будет превосходство/отличие "Bootstrap" от "% + Media Queries"?

Comment: в бутстрапе многое сделано уже. если вам захочется чего-то своего причудливого придется делать самому. если не захочется, велосипед изобретать будет слишком долго.

Comment: Если времени много на возню со стилями, то почему бы не заюзать media queries? А ежели времени маловато будет, то добро пожаловать в бутстрап.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap это не технология, это те же media queries, % и em. Это просто набор кода, который уже написан, и который решает распространенные задачи: сделать сетку, модальное окошко, менюшку выпадающюю и так далее.
А вот писать вам  адаптивную сетку самому или использовать bootstrap и другие адаптивные css фреймворки, стоит решить исходя из того кто вы и что у вас за проект. Если вы программист и планируете развиваться в этой роли, то хотя бы в одном проекте стоит пописать media queries  самому, чтобы вы понимали что это, какие там трудности, узнали проблемы организации классов и т.д. Если вы просто предприимчивый человек, который с минимальными затратами решил сделать супер сервис/сайт, то однозначно использовать готовые решения везде где только можно.